# SonarQube "Insufficient privileges"

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

A lot of our build jobs fail at the moment as of the "Insufficient privileges" problem since the update to 5.x. The problem should be fixed in SonarQube 5.1 as stated in [here](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-6091) but either it is in fact not fixed or there is another problem with the same error as we currently run SonarQube 5.1.1.

Here's an example of the error message:

```
08:27:13 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project server: Fail to decorate 'org.sonar.api.resources.File@b77a66[key=src/main/java/ch/ti8m/security/hwtoken/server/services/impl/TOTPAlgorithm.java,path=src/main/java/ch/ti8m/security/hwtoken/server/services/impl/TOTPAlgorithm.java,filename=TOTPAlgorithm.java,language=Java]': Insufficient privileges -> [Help 1]
08:27:13 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project server: Fail to decorate 'org.sonar.api.resources.File@b77a66[key=src/main/java/ch/ti8m/security/hwtoken/server/services/impl/TOTPAlgorithm.java,path=src/main/java/ch/ti8m/security/hwtoken/server/services/impl/TOTPAlgorithm.java,filename=TOTPAlgorithm.java,language=Java]'
08:27:13    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
08:27:13    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
08:27:13    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
08:27:13    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
08:27:13    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
08:27:13    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
08:27:13    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
08:27:13    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
08:27:13    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
08:27:13    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
08:27:13    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
08:27:13    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
08:27:13    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
08:27:13    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
08:27:13    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
08:27:13    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
08:27:13    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
08:27:13    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
08:27:13    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
08:27:13    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
08:27:13 Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Fail to decorate 'org.sonar.api.resources.File@b77a66[key=src/main/java/ch/ti8m/security/hwtoken/server/services/impl/TOTPAlgorithm.java,path=src/main/java/ch/ti8m/security/hwtoken/server/services/impl/TOTPAlgorithm.java,filename=TOTPAlgorithm.java,language=Java]'
08:27:13    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:41)
08:27:13    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:139)
08:27:13    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:132)
08:27:13    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
08:27:13    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
08:27:13    ... 19 more
08:27:13 Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Fail to decorate 'org.sonar.api.resources.File@b77a66[key=src/main/java/ch/ti8m/security/hwtoken/server/services/impl/TOTPAlgorithm.java,path=src/main/java/ch/ti8m/security/hwtoken/server/services/impl/TOTPAlgorithm.java,filename=TOTPAlgorithm.java,language=Java]'
08:27:13    at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.executeDecorator(DecoratorsExecutor.java:104)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.decorateResource(DecoratorsExecutor.java:87)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.decorateResource(DecoratorsExecutor.java:79)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.decorateResource(DecoratorsExecutor.java:79)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.execute(DecoratorsExecutor.java:71)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.batch.phases.DatabaseModePhaseExecutor.execute(DatabaseModePhaseExecutor.java:127)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:264)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:235)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:230)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:228)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:220)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:57)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:45)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:135)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:158)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
08:27:13    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
08:27:13    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
08:27:13    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
08:27:13    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
08:27:13    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
08:27:13    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:135)
08:27:13    ... 22 more
08:27:13 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Insufficient privileges
08:27:13    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.handleHttpException(ServerClient.java:137)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.request(ServerClient.java:107)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.request(ServerClient.java:99)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.request(ServerClient.java:87)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.batch.issue.tracking.DefaultServerLineHashesLoader.loadHashesFromWs(DefaultServerLineHashesLoader.java:47)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.batch.issue.tracking.DefaultServerLineHashesLoader.getLineHashes(DefaultServerLineHashesLoader.java:38)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.batch.issue.tracking.SourceHashHolder.initHashes(SourceHashHolder.java:52)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.batch.issue.tracking.SourceHashHolder.getHashedReference(SourceHashHolder.java:60)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.batch.issue.tracking.IssueTracking.mapIssues(IssueTracking.java:83)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.batch.issue.tracking.IssueTracking.track(IssueTracking.java:55)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.batch.issue.tracking.IssueTrackingDecorator.doDecorate(IssueTrackingDecorator.java:139)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.batch.issue.tracking.IssueTrackingDecorator.decorate(IssueTrackingDecorator.java:113)
08:27:13    at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.executeDecorator(DecoratorsExecutor.java:96)
08:27:13    ... 57 more
08:27:13 [ERROR] 
08:27:13 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
08:27:13 [ERROR] 
08:27:13 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
08:27:13 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
08:27:13 SonarQube analysis completed: FAILURE
08:27:13 Build step 'SonarQube' changed build result to FAILURE
08:27:13 Build step 'SonarQube' marked build as failure
```

Any ideas on how to fix it? The workaround to gave permission to anyone is a NoGo as the whole system must respect some NDAs and so the access is restricted.

Comment: Hi, are you sure that the user used to run the analysis has the "Browse" permission on the project ?

Comment: Hi Julien, yes I'm sure. Verified this once again and the configured "SonarQube account login" on our Jenkins installation has "Browse" permission on every Sonarqube project. Please let me know if you need further details!

Comment: blindly troubleshooting here: does the analysis actually succeed if you try and use another user with higher permissions?

Comment: Hi Seb, I've tried it with the admin credentials and the analysis was successfully finished. So how to go ahead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

User which runs analysis needs permissions:

- global: `Execute Analysis`
- project: `BROWSE` and `SEE SOURCE CODE`

Tested on [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/) 5.1.1.

Comment: Checked this once again and the permissions are exactly like this but the Sonar analysis is still failing with insufficient permissions.

Comment: Is user a member of `sonar-users`?

Comment: Yes, it is member of sonar-users.

Comment: Could you add the log with debug enabled? Sometimes when I can not solve the problem, I perform these steps: stop SonarQube server, remove directory `data/es` (it will be generated during startup) and start the server. It sounds silly, but already I solved the 3 problems in this way.

Comment: Naxt silly question: could you login to [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/) Web with this user? Mayby you have a problem with password?

Comment: Gotcha! That was the neccessary hint. Something with the credentials of the used account was wrong. After a reset of the credentials in the used Active Directory and re-entering them on Jenkins, everything works as expected.

Comment: @YvesSchumann: Then is it only a problem with LDAP or a problem with the LDAP and the user permission (global and project)?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the permissions is OK.

then I search the project in sonar,and see: the project have not had any history.
so I guess the project was created in sonar before.( may be as a moulde in parent pom.xml. then remove from the parent pom. )then I delete the project, and then run sonar again. and everything is OK

Comment: This should be a comment.