# Error while executing Sonarqube analysis " Insufficient privileges"

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I am trying to analyse java code through sonarqube. We have created a sonarqube server in our local environment and not using sonar cloud.

I tried using sonar maven plugin initially form this link [Sonar-Maven Plugin](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven)

However I faced an "Insufficient privileges" error.

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 22.185 s [INFO] Finished at: 2017-09-18T13:04:47+10:00 [INFO] Final Memory: 64M/589M [INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:
3.3.0.603:sonar (default-cli) on project testproject: Insufficient privileges ->  [Help 1] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal o rg.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar (default-cli) on  project testproject: Insufficient privileges
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor .java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor .java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor .java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThre adedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl eStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl. java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun cher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav a:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La uncher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java: 356) Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Insufficient privileg es
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(Exce ptionHandling.java:36)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(S cannerBootstrapper.java:80)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute(SonarQubeMojo.jav a:139)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(Default BuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor .java:208)
        ... 20 more Caused by: Insufficient privileges [ERROR] [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Then I tried to analyse using Sonar runner and I got same "Insufficient privileges" error again.

```
13:01:41.145 DEBUG: Upload report
13:01:41.179 DEBUG: POST 403 http://myserver:9000/api/ce/submit?projectKey=
SampleProject&projectName=sampleprojectWrapper | time=34ms
13:01:41.208 INFO: -------------------------------------------------------------
-----------
13:01:41.209 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
13:01:41.209 INFO: -------------------------------------------------------------
-----------
13:01:41.211 INFO: Total time: 12.919s
13:01:41.412 INFO: Final Memory: 52M/320M
13:01:41.413 INFO: -------------------------------------------------------------
-----------
13:01:41.414 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
Insufficient privileges
```

Then I created a new Sonarqube server and re-ran the execution and it worked fine.
I am trying to find out what was going wrong in the first server. The configuration for server and project was same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31560807/6309), check the SonarQube user permission that you are using for your job:

- `global`: Execute Analysis
- `project`: BROWSE and SEE SOURCE CODE

Those might be by default in your new SonarQube server.

As the [OP VVP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2404441/vvp) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46271107/error-while-executing-sonarqube-analysis-insufficient-privileges/46271893?noredirect=1#comment79507326_46271893):

> Yes the problem was "**Anyone**" group was removed somehow and this prevented code from being pushed to SonarQube.

See more at [Sonarqube / Security / Authorization / Group](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authorization#Authorization-Group).

Comment: Thanks. Yes the problem was "Anyone" group was removed somehow and this prevented code from being pushed to sonarqube.

Comment: @VVP Good catch. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 2):

Just an update on how this issue can be resolved.
I was using Sonar runner to analyse the code .
The issue was permissions for "Anyone" group was removed somehow. As per above answer, I added the permissions again, executed and I could see the results published.

[image: Sonar Group Configuration]