# SonarQube failed to analyze my solution

Tags: sonarqube, static-analysis, sonarcloud

I'm trying to setup SonarQube for my open source project but I've difficulties to automatize the process with my CI (AppVeyor).

SonarQube analysis failed with no more details except that I have to look at the log. But I don't know where to look at to find them. I've tried to do remote on the AppVeyor VM but I haven't anything relevant. Logs in the `.sonarqube` folder contain no more information that the one printed on the AppVeyor output.

Since it's the first time I tried to add SonarQube to a project, I have no clue where to look at. I've searched the error on internet without success.

Here is a part of the error I get on AppVeyor output:

```
[exec] 14:14:38.867 INFO: Analysis report generated in 421ms, dir size=436 KB
[exec] 14:14:39.012 INFO: Analysis reports compressed in 143ms, zip size=230 KB
[exec] 14:14:39.012 INFO: Analysis report generated in C:\projects\markify\src\.sonarqube\out\.sonar\scanner-report
[exec] 14:14:39.012 DEBUG: Upload report
[exec] 14:14:39.225 DEBUG: POST 403 https://sonarcloud.io/api/ce/submit?projectKey=Markify&projectName=Markify | time=212ms
[exec] 14:14:39.234 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[exec] 14:14:39.234 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
[exec] ##teamcity[buildProblem description='Analysis Failed: Check Build Log']]
[exec] 14:14:39.234 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[exec] 14:14:39.234 INFO: Total time: 35.907s
[exec] 14:14:39.324 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
[exec] 14:14:39.324 ERROR: Insufficient privileges
[exec] 14:14:39.324 ERROR: 
[exec] 14:14:39.324 ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[exec] 14:14:39.323 INFO: Final Memory: 69M/168M
[exec] 14:14:39.324 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[exec] 14:14:39.324 DEBUG: Execution getVersion
[exec] 14:14:39.325 DEBUG: Execution stop
[exec] Process returned exit code 1
[exec] The SonarQube Scanner did not complete successfully
[exec] 14:14:39.535  Creating a summary markdown file...
[exec] 14:14:39.537  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
[exec] [EndPhase] : Failed. Check Log
[exec] ##teamcity[buildProblem description='sonar-scanner return non 0 error code']]
[exec] [CxxSonarQubeMsbuidRunner] Failed analyze project, check log
BUILD FAILED
```

And here a build where the analysis has failed : https://ci.appveyor.com/project/Takumii/markify/build/1.0.501

The project can be found here : https://github.com/Julien-Pires/Markify/tree/sonarqube

I'm using NAnt to execute the Sonarqube analysis. All parameters used for Sonarqube can be found here: https://github.com/Julien-Pires/Markify/blob/sonarqube/default.build

Answer (score 0):

```
 [exec] 14:14:39.324 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
 [exec] 14:14:39.324 ERROR: Insufficient privileges
```

This suggest a permission issue, as I [detailed before in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46271893/6309).
See "[Authorization / Group](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authorization#Authorization-Group)" to check if you have the necessary permission to post a SonarQube analysis.

Comment: I've checked group permission for "Anyone" and "Members" no one had permission to Analyze nor create project. So, I have activated the permissions but it changes nothing. I've still the same error. I'm trying to upload analysis report to SonarCloud.io and not a private server.

Comment: @JulienPires Is there any connectivity issue to sonarCloud.io?

Comment: No, SonarCloud.io connectivity seems ok. To test it I've tried to remove the login parameters and I get a different error stating that I haven't the right to access the server. I have no clue what is triggering the insufficent privileges. I have configured the group with access to everything. And the login used match with my account which is organization admin.

Comment: @JulienPires Did you try the maven build with the -X option, just to see if the error callstack might give some clues?

Comment: I have already set the parameter sonar.verbose=true which seems to be equivalent of -X.

Answer (score 0):

Please sure that, you have necessary access rights to the sonarqube server where u are trying to post your analysis report.